# Change the visibility of dynamically created Layouts in onBackPressed

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, android-view, onbackpressed

I need one help , I have dynamically created Linear Layout , i have to change the visibility of the Created Linear Layout.

My Effort show far :

```
for (int i=0;i<qty;i++) {
            final View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(BookingDetails.this).inflate(R.layout.dynamic_truck_item, null);
            view_visible.add(false);
            final LinearLayout view_dd=(LinearLayout)view1.findViewById(R.id.view_dd);
}
```

Back Press:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (backPressedToExitOnce) {
            super.onBackPressed();

        } else {
            this.backPressedToExitOnce = true;

            // Here i have to set the visibility of created linear layout to VIEW.GONE

        }

    }
```

Comment: Why are you putting that code on a loop?

Comment: because , i want to create the linear layout dynamically depends upon the qty.

Comment: add all new layouts to array and then set visibility to all items in array on onBackPressed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an ArrayList to hold all the references to the LienarLayouts

```
private ArrayList<View> collectionOfViews = new ArrayList();
```

When inflating your layout add the views to the List:

```
for (int i=0;i<qty;i++) {
        final View view1 = LayoutInflater.from(BookingDetails.this).inflate(R.layout.dynamic_truck_item, null);
        view_visible.add(false);
        final LinearLayout view_dd=(LinearLayout)view1.findViewById(R.id.view_dd);
        collectionOfViews.add(view_dd);
}
```

Then in `onBackPressed` set the visibility using:

```
for(View view : collectionOfViews) {
    view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: but i defined the id for my linear layout in xml , if i take the array of LinearLayout in class level then how we define the id in the loop . if you add some more code it will be more helpful to me

Comment: The id is used only during inflation, after that you end up with a reference to the View object, that is enough to modify it's visibility. I have updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

your should take out **View view1** from loop and after that you should take **ViewGroup** for adding view at index.

```
((ViewGroup)view1.findViewById(R.id.background)).addView(child, index);
```

after that at your **onBackPressed()** method you can get view by index and simply set visibility to gone/visible.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() { 
   ((ViewGroup)view1.findViewById(R.id.background)).getChildAt(index).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: That would work only if the `view1` has no other children